# How to filter entries in nested List by ID in nested List in elasticsearch with java?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

Basically I do have a Set of a Records which has a Set of NestedRecords included:

```
Set<Record> records;
```

These are the classes:

```
public class Record {
  String id;
  Set<NestedRecord> nestedRecords;
}

public class NestedRecord {
  String nestedId;
  int count;
}
```

What I want to achieve is filter the out the entries in the nestedRecords list by a Set of nested ids.
So I only want the nestedRecords in the List in Records which include the id's in my set nested Id's

Let's say this is my Set:

```
Set<String> nestedIds = new HashSet<String>() {{
add("a");
add("b");
}};
```

So this is how I do it, but it always filters out everything.

```
TermsQueryBuilder recordExists = QueryBuilders.termsQuery("NESTED_RECORDS.NESTED_ID",Lists.newArrayList(nestedIds).toString());

NestedQueryBuilder nestedRecords = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("NESTED_RECORDS", recordExists, ScoreMode.Total);

BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQuery.must(nestedRecords);
query.filter(boolQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually use Kotlin, so I don't know how java does it, but I think your `toString()` is wrong there

```java
TermsQueryBuilder recordExists = nestedId.termsQuery("nestedRecords.nestedId",Lists.newArrayList(nestedIds).toString());
```

can be

```java
TermsQueryBuilder recordExists = QueryBuilders.termsQuery("nestedRecords.nestedId", Lists.newArrayList(nestedIds));
```

and

```java
NestedQueryBuilder nestedRecords = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("NESTED_RECORD", recordExists, ScoreMode.Total);
```

```java
NestedQueryBuilder nestedRecords = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("nestedRecords", recordExists, ScoreMode.Total);
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not working.

Comment: can you show me your mappings? `GET http://localhost:9200/record`

Comment: This is just an example, so I do not have access to mappings

Comment: but thats how nested queries work. Check the docs you canhttps://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html#nested-query-ex-query  -- you can also try IDs Query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html